# UIPanGesture With NSTimer Issue

Tags: ios, swift, timer, gesture

i'm facing an issue 
i have a view controller that contains both a Pan gesture and an NSTimer that has a selector that gets called every second
the problem is every time the timer is activated the label i'm trying to move using the pan gesture return to its origin position automatically.
what might the reason be ?

here is the code

```
import UIKit

class gameViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var img1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gameDifficultyLabel: UILabel!

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var timeManager = TimerManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timerLabel.text = "\(timeManager.displayedTime(timeManager.time!))"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateTime", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let difficulty = timeManager.difficulties {
            switch difficulty {
            case .Easy:
                gameDifficultyLabel.text = "Easy"
            case .Medium:
                gameDifficultyLabel.text = "Medium"
            case .Hard:
                gameDifficultyLabel.text = "Hard"
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func panGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)
        if let view = sender.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        }
        sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func updateTime() {
        let shouldStop = timeManager.updateTime()
        timerLabel.text = timeManager.displayedTime(timeManager.time)
        if shouldStop {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE : 
i have updated the code.
adding labels programmatically solved the issue but i had another issue 
here is the code.

class gameViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var numbersContainers: [UIImageView]!
@IBOutlet var numbersLabel: [UILabel]!

@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gameDifficultyLabel: UILabel!

var LabelsBackground = [UIImageView]()
var Labels = [UILabel]()

var timer = NSTimer()
var timeManager = TimerManager()

var panGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timerLabel.text = "\(timeManager.displayedTime(timeManager.time!))"
    self.createLabelsBackground()
    self.setUpLabelsBackground()
    self.addLabelsBackground()

    self.createLabels()
    self.setUpLabels()
    self.addLabels()

    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panAction:")
    panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1

}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateTime", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    self.addPanGesture()
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let difficulty = timeManager.difficulties {
        switch difficulty {
        case .Easy:
            gameDifficultyLabel.text = "Easy"
        case .Medium:
            gameDifficultyLabel.text = "Medium"
        case .Hard:
            gameDifficultyLabel.text = "Hard"
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func updateTime() {
    let shouldStop = timeManager.updateTime()
    timerLabel.text = timeManager.displayedTime(timeManager.time)
    if shouldStop {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
func createLabelsBackground() {
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        if let img = UIImage(named: "noContainer") {
            LabelsBackground.append(UIImageView(image: img))
        }

    }
}
func setUpLabelsBackground() {
    for i in 0..<10 {
        LabelsBackground[i].frame = numbersContainers[i].frame
        LabelsBackground[i].center = numbersContainers[i].center
    }
}
func addLabelsBackground() {
    for background in LabelsBackground {
        self.view.addSubview(background)
    }
}

func createLabels() {
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        Labels.append(UILabel())
    }
}
func setUpLabels() {
    for i in 0..<10 {
        Labels[i].frame = numbersLabel[i].frame
        Labels[i].center = numbersLabel[i].center
        Labels[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        Labels[i].userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
func addLabels() {
    for label in Labels {
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }
}

func addPanGesture(){
    for label in Labels {
        label.text = "10"
        label.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
}

func panAction(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print("panAction")
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    if let myView = recognizer.view {
        myView.center = CGPoint(x: myView.center.x + translation.x, y: myView.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

}

just to clarify 
@IBOutlet var numbersLabel: [UILabel]!
var Labels = UILabel

numbersLabels are empty labels added using storyboard just for positioning when creating labels programmatically.

the problem is the labels created programmatically and added to the labels array are not responding.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: no im not using auto layout at the moment

Comment: still the same affect, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do have Auto Layout enabled (it is on by default).  If you do not specify any constraints for a view (such as your label), the Storyboard will create them for you at build time.  You can verify this by looking at the *Size Inspector* settings for your label.

When `updateTime()` is called, Auto Layout places your label back to its original position according the constraints that were created for it automatically by the Storyboard.

To solve this issue, you can either:

1) Create your label programmatically instead of creating it in the Storyboard.

OR

2) Add explicit constraints for your label position in the Storyboard, then create `@IBOutlet`s to those constraints and move the label in code by changing the `constant` property of those constraints instead of changing its frame (center).

Comment: but i have not used any auto layout for it yet. how did it get enable ?

Comment: Auto Layout is on by default.

Comment: ok thanks, i will try to do it programmatically now and check what will happen.

Comment: By default, user interaction is `false` for labels.  If your label is called `myLabel`, then set `myLabel.userInteraction = true` after creating the label.

Comment: i have done it already, the labels are in an outlet collection and i applied the gesture using a loop labels[i].addGestureRecoginzer(pangesture) but it is not working.

Comment: Every label needs its own gestureRecognizer. You can't create just one.

Comment: i have updated the post. Ok i will try to create multiple gestures... THANKS and sorry for bothering.